# How to find MIN and MAX of two columns from TWO different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, max, min

**TABLE1** *contains the time of the first call made by an agent and the time of the last call made by an agent for every day GROUPED BY agent name.*

```
AGENT      FIRSTCALL           LASTCALL
A         8/5/2013 10:59    8/5/2013 19:50
A         8/6/2013 11:06    8/6/2013 19:50
B         8/5/2013 10:33    8/5/2013 10:35
C         8/5/2013 10:04    8/5/2013 9:56
C         8/6/2013 10:02    8/6/2013 9:47
D         8/5/2013 10:37    8/5/2013 18:47
D         8/6/2013 14:58    8/6/2013 18:19
D         8/6/2013 10:01    8/6/2013 9:59
E         8/5/2013 12:29    8/5/2013 18:51
E         8/6/2013 12:05    8/6/2013 18:48
F         8/6/2013 11:15    8/6/2013 19:49
G         8/5/2013 10:04    8/5/2013 10:09
G         8/6/2013 10:39    8/6/2013 9:54
```

**TABLE2** *consists of agent name and daily login and logout time for that agent.*

```
AGENT            LOGIN               LOGOUT
A        2013-08-05 11:02:52    2013-08-05 20:05:45
A        2013-08-06 11:00:30    2013-08-06 20:06:47
B        2013-08-05 08:59:07    2013-08-05 18:01:58
B        2013-08-06 09:11:43    2013-08-06 18:08:49
C        2013-08-05 08:58:21    2013-08-05 17:59:29
C        2013-08-06 08:59:13    2013-08-06 18:03:53
D        2013-08-05 10:37:55    2013-08-05 19:56:20
D        2013-08-06 10:37:04    2013-08-06 20:00:43
E        2013-08-06 09:20:50    2013-08-06 18:00:35
F        2013-08-05 10:58:06    2013-08-05 20:00:24
F        2013-08-06 10:49:19    2013-08-06 20:01:37
G        2013-08-06 11:00:17    2013-08-06 19:58:31
H        2013-08-05 09:00:38    2013-08-05 18:16:16
H        2013-08-06 08:56:38    2013-08-06 17:57:00
```

I need to join these tables in such a manner that I get AGENT, FIRSTCALL, LASTCALL, LOGIN, LOGOUT for each day. In the example above, I've only listed data for two days but the data exists for over two years (>700 days).

*Previously, I've tried connecting these tables via 'AGENT' but that results in multiple records. What is the way out?*

Comment: Add date_of_First_Call and Date_of_Login in the join condition.

Comment: Where do `min` and `max` fit in? You seem to have one entry per agent per day on each table, so what would you aggregate on? Are these stored as dates or strings; and will they always line up on date? (e.g. could an agent log in at 23:59 and take their first call at 00:01, and if so how should that be handled?)

Comment: I need min max on all four columns. Dates are in varchar (and in different formats) which is why I am unable to use a join on the dates. But, if that is the only way, I'll have to change the formats by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this will work. May be there'is some better way to convert timestamp to date.

```
select T1.AGENT, T1.FIRSTCALL, T1.LASTCALL, T2.LOGIN, T2.LOGOUT
from Table1 T1
    inner join Table2 T2 on
        T2.AGENT = T1.AGENT and
        to_char(T1.FIRSTCALL, 'YYYYMMDD') = to_char(T2.LOGIN, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

see [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ca04/11) with example

Answer (score -1):

```
select T1.AGENT, T1.FIRSTCALL, T1.LASTCALL, T2.LOGIN, T2.LOGOUT
from Table1 T1
    inner join Table2 T2 on
        T2.AGENT = T1.AGENT and
        to_char(T1.FIRSTCALL, 'YYYYMMDD') = to_char(T2.LOGIN, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: Answer to this question was posted over 4 years ago. Why are you posting the same answer again now?